# How do I generate const or test data in C#?

Tags: c#

I tend to write lots of test using boost/unit_test and I tend to generate lots of const data - for instance

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/std/map.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::assign;
using namespace std;

const vector<int> my_vector_of_ints = ba::list_of(15)(23)(43)(22)(5)(78);
const map<int, string> my_map = ba::map_list_of(5, "abc")(7, "ddd");
```

etc. etc. etc.

How do I go about this stuff in C# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
readonly List<int> myListOfInts 
    = new List<int> { 15, 23, 43, 22, 5, 78 };
readonly Dictionary<int, string> myMap 
    = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 5, "abc" }, { 7, "ddd" } };
```

Now C#'s `const` doesn't mean the same thing as C++'s `const` so you will need to realize that these instances are mutable.  I have marked these fields as `readonly` which is about as close as you are going to get.

Comment: You cannot use the var keyword to declare class members - only local method variables.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 3 you can use [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
public static class TestData
{
    public static readonly List<int> my_vector_of_ints 
       = new List<int> { 15, 24, 43, 22, 5, 78 };

    public static readonly Dictionary<int,string> my_map 
       = new Dictionary<int,string> { {5, "abc"}, {7, "ddd" } };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<int> MyInts = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new int[] {
    15, 23, 43, 22, 5, 78
});
```

Unfortunately, .Net does not have a read-only dictionary type.

You can use a mutable dictionary like this, but if you expose the dictionary to other code, the other code will be able to add or remove entries in it.

```
static readonly Dictionary<int, string> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> {
    { 5, "abc" },
    { 7, "ddd" }
};
```

The `readonly` keyword in the declaration means that the variable cannot be re-assigned (like a `const` pointer in C++, which cannot be re-assigned to point to something else).  It does not mean that the object cannot be mutated.  However, `ReadOnlyCollection` is immutable by design.

**EDIT**: To make `const` structs, make your `structs` immutable (Don't have an set methods, etc).  This is good practice in general for structs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Autofixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/).  It can substantially simplify setting up your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate test data using [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/)

Through a fluent, extensible interface, NBuilder allows you to rapidly create test data, automatically assigning values to properties and public fields that are of type of the built in .NET data types (e.g. ints and strings). NBuilder allows you to override for properties you are interested in using lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

C# has [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).